# Create same models in client that are returned from WCF service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have a WCF service with limited methods to expose to our other applications. 
So my questions is, we have created our models in different layers and they are referenced in service. But if I want to call this service in one of our applications, I am getting output from service methods on client side like:

```
List<UserManager.ServiceRef.User>
```

So when I create a View on our client side MVC app, Can I just pass this model returned from service to MVC view? Is it a good practice? Any security concerns?
Please suggest.

Comment: Does this user object contains sensitive information? Do you really need to send all these data to view, if you need only id, name, surname,email etc , just take these information from that list object and create another list of object. But this model contains what you need , as far as I know there is no security concerns. It is like creating a model and returning it to view.

Comment: Yes, i am returning some sensitive information from service. Do you think still it is not a problem?

Comment: Do you need that information at view ?

Comment: But I always recommend creating a specific model for that view to represent data.